# Pygame with version of Python from EPD

Tags: python, pygame

I can't figure out how to install [Pygame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame) on [OS X 10.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard). I installed the version of [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) provided by [Enthought Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) (EPD) - as required by the course instructor at MIT - and then installed the version of Pygame for Snow Leopard and Python 2.7. Unfortunately, when I try to do `import pygame`, I get an ImportError (No module named pygame). How do I fix this problem?

Comment: The pygame module is for python 2.7 provided by python.org not python provided by apple. Which one do you have?

Comment: Looks like he has the version of Python provided by Enthought Python Distribution (EPD) Which can be found at  [link](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a hard time in the beginning but found it to be easy after reading 
[this site](http://www.scidav.org/installs/visionegg)

- Step1: cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
- Step2: sudo ln -s 7.3 2.7 [The 7.3 is the epd version and the 2.7 is
  the python version, obviously change it to the version of python and
  epd that you have]
- Step3: Grab the installer from the pygame website. Download and
  install.

Voila! pygame is working